# A dropdown with checklist

Tags: categories, dropdown

I'm working on a wordpress website now but I have a problem with a dropdown on a taxonomy.
This code is in a public form so that the visitor send a recipe, taxonomy is the ingredients which already registered on the website.

With the current dropdown, everything works fine, displaying taxonomies, and viewing once in the admin.

With this code, i have a basic dropdown, but i want one with a checklist.

```
 <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'tab_index=25&taxonomy=ingredient-listing&name=ingredient-listing&show_option_none='.__('Choisir','FoodRecipe').'&hide_empty=0' ); ?>
```

I try with this code :

```
<?php wp_category_checklist( 'tab_index=25&taxonomy=ingredient-listing&name=ingredient-listing&show_option_none='.__('Choisir','FoodRecipe').'&hide_empty=0' ); ?>
```

and this code in functions.php

```
function wp_category_checklist( $post_id = 0, $descendants_and_self = 0, $selected_cats = false, $popular_cats = false, $walker = null, $checked_ontop = true ) {
wp_terms_checklist( $post_id, array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'descendants_and_self' => $descendants_and_self,
    'selected_cats' => $selected_cats,
    'popular_cats' => $popular_cats,
    'walker' => $walker,
    'checked_ontop' => $checked_ontop
) );
}
```

But doesn't work, i have a Fatal error.

The function category checklist already exists but wp-admin side, so I think not accessible side wp-content ...

Do you have any idea?

Thanks you very much

Nathy

Comment: Post the complete error message please

Comment: Hello ! Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_terms_checklist() in /web/tambouill/www/wp-content/themes/food-recipes/functions.php on line 630

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_terms_checklist()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php) is an admin side function as you suspect.

I don't recommend trying to load admin side code on the front end (especially if you are not very very familiar with its inner workings) so essentially you are left with rolling your own code to create the checklist.

You should be able to use the `wp_terms_checklist()` code as a model, but it may be that that code is far more complicated than you need it to be. It is hard to tell without more detail about your specific problem.